# not understanding the output of a static initializers

Tags: java

so currently I m preparing for Oracle certified associate java...and I 've run to this question: what is the output of the following code

the solution says that s the output is:  u u ucrcr

I know that static initializers only gets called once so 
i don t get why the third u is printed

```
package com.company;

class Order {

    static String result = "";

    {
        result += "c";
    }

    static {
        result += "u";
    }

    {
        result += "r";
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print(Order.result + " ");

        System.out.print(Order.result + " ");

        new Order();

        new Order();

        System.out.print(Order.result + " ");

    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's appending to the existing string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It outputs `Order.result` 3 times, that's why `u` is printed 3 times.

After the order class is loaded, `result` is u. You do `System.out.print(Order.result + " ");` to output it the first time, the you do `System.out.print(Order.result + " ");` to output it the second time. Then you create 2 instances of the Order class, thus appending "cr" twice, and how your `result` is `ucrcr`, so you output `ucrcr`, where you have your third you.

You must take into account the fact that `System.out.print` is being used here.